# Can't redirect to an other FXML

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Plop,

Me here because i need help, i'm totally lost, i've tried many times but still got this error.

Me trying to redirect the user on a login page to a signin page when he click on a button.

Me have error ():

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:395)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Me try to redirect the user from (Login.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packages.home.Controller">
   <left>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="346.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Text fill="#f5f5f5" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="218.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MY FIT">
               <font>
                  <Font size="39.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text fill="#f5f5f5" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="256.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Gérer vos séances sportives et plus encore" wrappingWidth="347.3798828125">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Button fx:id="btnCreate" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="314.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffff;" text="Se connecter" textFill="#00a8cc">
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect></Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="356.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="175.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="158.0" promptText="Nom d'utilisateur" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="158.0" promptText="Mot de passe" />
            <Button fx:id="btnConnect" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="313.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" text="Se connecter" textFill="WHITE">
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Hyperlink layoutX="48.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Vous avez oubliez votre mot de passe ?" />
            <Text fill="#00a8cc" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="121.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Authentification">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Button fx:id="btnClose" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="-1.0" minWidth="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="60.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" text="Quitter" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label fx:id="lblErrors" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="154.0" textFill="#dd1717" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Main Controller (me redirecting the user in handleButtonAction - btnCreate) :

```
package packages.home;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Controller extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Button btnClose;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;

    @FXML
    private Label lblErrors;

    @FXML
    private Button btnConnect;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCreate;

    /// --
    Connection laConnection = GestionConnection.getLaConnection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;


    public void handleButtonAction(MouseEvent event) throws IOException{

        if (event.getSource() == btnClose) {
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("Fermeture de l'application.");
        }

        if (event.getSource() == btnConnect) {

            //login here
            if (logIn().equals("Success")) {

                // On affiche une nouvelle scene
                try {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    stage.setTitle("MyFit - Mon Dashboard");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                    stage.show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);

                }

                //add you loading or delays - ;-)
                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
                Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

                //stage.setMaximized(true);
                stage.close();


            }
        }

        if (event.getSource() == btnCreate) {

            // On affiche une nouvelle scene
            try {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Create.fxml"));
                Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                stage.setTitle("MyFit - Inscription");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                stage.show();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);

            }

            //add you loading or delays - ;-)
            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
            Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

            //stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.close();




            }


    }



    private String logIn() {

        String status = "Success";
        String username = txtUsername.getText();
        String password = txtPassword.getText();

        if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {

            setLblErrors(Color.RED, "Champs vides.");
            status = "Error";

        } else {

            //query
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM admins Where username = ? and password = ?";

            try {

                // On test la requête
                System.out.println("Hello");
                preparedStatement = laConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                if (!resultSet.next()) {
                    setLblErrors(Color.TOMATO, "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect");
                    status = "Error";

                } else {
                    setLblErrors(Color.GREEN, "Authentification réussite, redirection en cours ...");
                    showMessageDialog(null, "Vous êtes bien connecté");

                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {

                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                status = "Exception";
            }
        }
        return status;

    }


    private void setLblErrors(Color color, String text) {
        lblErrors.setTextFill(color);
        lblErrors.setText(text);
        System.out.println(text);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Me try to print this fxml :'( :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packages.home.CreateController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="234.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="243.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffff;">
         <children>
            <Text fill="#00a8cc" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="37.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Inscription">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="393.0" prefHeight="107.0" prefWidth="700.0">
         <children>
            <CheckBox accessibleRoleDescription="ndr" layoutX="385.0" layoutY="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Confirmer l'inscription." textFill="WHITE" />
            <Button fx:id="btnCreate1" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="134.0" style="-fx-background-color: #d63447;" text="Rejoindre MyFit" textFill="WHITE">
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect>
               <font>
                  <Font size="16.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="154.0" layoutY="178.0" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="455.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="-29.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="442.0" promptText="E-mail" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <TextField layoutX="125.0" layoutY="134.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Nom d'utilisateur" />
      <TextField layoutX="394.0" layoutY="134.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="173.0" promptText="Nom" />
      <TextField layoutX="393.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="122.0" promptText="Pays" />
      <DatePicker layoutX="125.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="147.0" promptText="Date de naissance" />
      <TextField layoutX="126.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="173.0" promptText="Nom d'utilisateur " />
      <PasswordField layoutX="393.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="173.0" promptText="Mot de passe" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

CreateController:

```
package packages.home;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class CreateController implements Initializable {

private final AnchorPane rootPane;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtName;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtFirstname;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtEmail;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtCountry;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField txtPassword;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCreate1;

    public CreateController(AnchorPane rootPane) {
this.rootPane = rootPane
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

Me a student new to Java and JavaFX and i'm sure it have a lot of possibilies.

If you have any questions regarding this subject feel free to answer.

Me thanks in advance for your help, me really appreciate.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) (format it as [code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). Identify the line that's throwing the exception.

Comment: Me did it, of course i made a mistake here sorry :(

Comment: There's no "Caused By" clauses?

Comment: Nope that's why i'm septic

Comment: When does the exception happen? When you press `btnCreate`?

Comment: yes every time i press the button the exception come in the console

Comment: Can you include the `import` statements for the `Controller` class?

Comment: My _guess_ is that you have an event handler method which has the wrong event type as a parameter. Which `MouseEvent` did you import? Make sure it's `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent` and not AWT's.

Comment: Also, unless you've taken special care to handle it, the fact your `CreateController` class does not have a no-arg constructor will cause problems as well.

Comment: import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent; i've got this import in my main Controller (The login page)

Comment: i've added this in the constructor this.rootPane = rootPane; and creat an attribut : private final AnchorPane rootPane;

Comment: I'm still having the same exception message :(

Comment: I've added the import in the Login controller

Comment: I reverted your question to the old error. If you have a new problem please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't forget to provide a [mre] demonstrating the problem and the [full stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/6395627) of any error(s) you're getting. See [ask] for more information. All that being said, please try to find an existing Q&A before asking a new question; it's possible your new problem has already been solved in another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your "Login.fxml" FXML file, you have this button:

```xml
<Button fx:id="btnCreate" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="314.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
        onAction="#handleButtonAction" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" 
        prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="111.0" 
        style="-fx-background-color: #ffff;" text="Se connecter" textFill="#00a8cc">
```

Notice you defined both `onAction` *and* `onMouseClicked` to invoke the same method. Yet in `Controller` you have:

```java
public void handleButtonAction(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
    // method body omitted for brevity
}
```

This won't work. The `onAction` expects an `ActionEvent` and the `onMouseClicked` expects a `MouseEvent`. You need to either:

1. **Bad:** Change the parameter type to a supertype of both `ActionEvent` and `MouseEvent` (e.g. `Event`).
2. **Good:** Remove either `onAction` or `onMouseClicked` from the button element in the FXML. Preferably you'd remove the latter as the `onAction` handler is the proper way to do something when a button is interacted with.

   If you keep `onAction` then you need to change from `MouseEvent` to `ActionEvent`.

Option two is by far the best option. Keeping both handlers will cause the method to be invoked twice.

---

You will also have a problem with your `CreateController`. When you define a controller with `fx:controller`, and don't use a custom controller factory, the `FXMLLoader` attempts to reflectively create the controller via the no-arg constructor. Since `CreateController` does not have a no-arg constructor this will cause an exception to be thrown (specifically a `NoSuchMethodException`, I believe).

There are at least three possible solutions:

1. Remove `fx:controller` from the FXML file and manually set the controller instance:

   ```java
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setController(new CreateController(/* AnchorPane instance */));
   // invoke #load() **after** setting the controller
   ```
2. Keep the `fx:controller` in the FXML and set a custom controller factory:

   ```java
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> {
     if (clazz == CreateController.class) {
       return new CreateController(/* AnchorPane instance */);
     }
     throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   });
   // invoke #load() **after** setting the controller factory
   ```
3. Keep the `fx:controller`, use a no-arg constructor in `CreateController`, and add a way to pass the `AnchorPane` after the fact:

   ```java
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
   // configure loader...
   loader.load();
   // must invoke #load() **before** getting the controller instance
   loader.<CreateController>getController().setAnchorPane(/* AnchorPane insatnce */);
   ```

   In this case, it's best to just get rid of the constructor in `CreateController` since it no longer does anything. If no constructor is declared then an implicit no-arg "default constructor" is added by the compiler.

Comment: i updated the post with the new button that i got and the new error :(

Comment: i've done the 3rd option , create a no arg constructor and add a way to pass the anchorpane but this is the line i have an error on : <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packages.home.CreateController">

Comment: Don't keep changing your question. This answer was in response to your original question and changing the question removes the context of the answer. I believe my answer solves your original problem (the bad argument type) and provides a solution to a problem you'd have in the future (the controller's constructor). If you have a new problem after applying the changes recommended by this answer then please feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with a [mre] demonstrating the problem and the _full_ stack trace of any error(s) you're getting.