# Having an issue when i try to redirect a user on a new FXML

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

---

I'm a student new to Java and JavaFX.

I can launch my main with my main fxml file which are :

**Main file :**

```
package packages.home;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setTitle("mySportApp - Melvin CARRERE");

        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700, 500));

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

**This is my Login.fxml file (This Fxml file is print when i launch my main):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packages.home.Controller">
   <left>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="346.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Text fill="#f5f5f5" layoutX="137.0" layoutY="218.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="MY FIT">
               <font>
                  <Font size="39.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Text fill="#f5f5f5" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="256.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Gérer vos séances sportives et plus encore" wrappingWidth="347.3798828125">
               <font>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Button fx:id="btnCreate" layoutX="140.0" layoutY="314.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffff;" text="Se connecter" textFill="#00a8cc">
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect></Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </left>
   <right>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="356.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <TextField fx:id="txtUsername" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="175.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="158.0" promptText="Nom d'utilisateur" />
            <PasswordField fx:id="txtPassword" layoutX="84.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="158.0" promptText="Mot de passe" />
            <Button fx:id="btnConnect" layoutX="108.0" layoutY="313.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButtonAction" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="33.0" prefWidth="111.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" text="Se connecter" textFill="WHITE">
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect></Button>
            <Hyperlink layoutX="48.0" layoutY="452.0" text="Vous avez oubliez votre mot de passe ?" />
            <Text fill="#00a8cc" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="121.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Authentification">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
            <Button fx:id="btnClose" layoutX="257.0" layoutY="-1.0" minWidth="49.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="60.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" text="Quitter" textFill="WHITE" />
            <Label fx:id="lblErrors" layoutX="87.0" layoutY="278.0" prefHeight="23.0" prefWidth="154.0" textFill="#dd1717" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

The controller of this Login.fxml file is :

```
package packages.home;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class Controller extends Application {

    @FXML
    private Button btnClose;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;

    @FXML
    private Label lblErrors;

    @FXML
    private Button btnConnect;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCreate;

    /// --
    Connection laConnection = GestionConnection.getLaConnection();
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;


    public void handleButtonAction(MouseEvent event) throws IOException{

        if (event.getSource() == btnClose) {
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("Fermeture de l'application.");
        }

        if (event.getSource() == btnConnect) {

            //login here
            if (logIn().equals("Success")) {

                // On affiche une nouvelle scene
                try {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    stage.setTitle("MyFit - Mon Dashboard");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                    stage.show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);

                }

                //add you loading or delays - ;-)
                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
                Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

                //stage.setMaximized(true);
                stage.close();


            }
        }

        if (event.getSource() == btnCreate) {

            // On affiche une nouvelle scene
            try {
                FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Create.fxml"));
                Parent root2 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                stage.setTitle("MyFit - Inscription");
                stage.setScene(new Scene(root2));
                stage.show();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);

            }

            //add you loading or delays - ;-)
            Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
            Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

            //stage.setMaximized(true);
            stage.close();




            }


    }



    private String logIn() {

        String status = "Success";
        String username = txtUsername.getText();
        String password = txtPassword.getText();

        if(username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {

            setLblErrors(Color.RED, "Champs vides.");
            status = "Error";

        } else {

            //query
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM admins Where username = ? and password = ?";

            try {

                // On test la requête
                System.out.println("Hello");
                preparedStatement = laConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                if (!resultSet.next()) {
                    setLblErrors(Color.TOMATO, "Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect");
                    status = "Error";

                } else {
                    setLblErrors(Color.GREEN, "Authentification réussite, redirection en cours ...");
                    showMessageDialog(null, "Vous êtes bien connecté");

                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {

                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                status = "Exception";
            }
        }
        return status;

    }


    private void setLblErrors(Color color, String text) {
        lblErrors.setTextFill(color);
        lblErrors.setText(text);
        System.out.println(text);
    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Every time i'm trying to redirect my user on an other fxml, when i click on the button btnCreate or BtnConnect it should redirect.

**My problem is that everytime i click on one of both button, this message error is print in the console and i can't show the new scene :**

```
Problème de BDD Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
avr. 01, 2020 1:18:08 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 10.0.2-internal
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:395)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8865)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3876)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Scene.java:3604)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2613)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:395)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

For exemple this is the **Create.fxml file** that i want to show each time the user will click on btnCreate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Glow?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00a8cc;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packages.home.CreateController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="234.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="243.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffff;">
         <children>
            <Text fill="#00a8cc" layoutX="66.0" layoutY="37.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Inscription">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Text>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="393.0" prefHeight="107.0" prefWidth="700.0">
         <children>
            <CheckBox accessibleRoleDescription="ndr" layoutX="385.0" layoutY="45.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Confirmer l'inscription." textFill="WHITE" />
            <Button fx:id="btnCreate1" layoutX="216.0" layoutY="35.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="134.0" style="-fx-background-color: #d63447;" text="Rejoindre MyFit" textFill="WHITE">
               <effect>
                  <Glow />
               </effect>
               <font>
                  <Font size="16.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="154.0" layoutY="178.0" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="455.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="-29.0" layoutY="19.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="442.0" promptText="E-mail" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <TextField layoutX="125.0" layoutY="134.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Nom d'utilisateur" />
      <TextField layoutX="394.0" layoutY="134.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="173.0" promptText="Nom" />
      <TextField layoutX="393.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="122.0" promptText="Pays" />
      <DatePicker layoutX="125.0" layoutY="267.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="147.0" promptText="Date de naissance" />
      <TextField layoutX="126.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="173.0" promptText="Nom d'utilisateur " />
      <PasswordField layoutX="393.0" layoutY="346.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="173.0" promptText="Mot de passe" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

And this is the CreateController which will be my users creation account part :

```
package packages.home;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class CreateController implements Initializable {

    private AnchorPane rootPane;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtName;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtFirstname;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtEmail;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtCountry;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField txtPassword;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker datePicker;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @FXML
    private Button btnCreate1;

    public CreateController(AnchorPane rootPane) {
        this.rootPane = rootPane;
    }

    public CreateController() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
// configure loader...
        Object load = loader.load();
// must invoke #load() **before** getting the controller instance
        loader.<CreateController>getController().wait(rootPane);
    }

    private void wait(AnchorPane rootPane) {
    }


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

If you want more info, yesterday night, when i was clicking on btnConnect, the connection at the database was working and i was redirect on an other page.

The btnCreate redirection never worked.

Thanks you for all your help and all your support on this issue.

If you need any information regarding this subject let me know.

Have a good day !

Comment: This is the same problem you were having before: `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`. You haven't applied the fix given in the answer to [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60957719/6395627).

Comment: And you incorrectly applied the fix for your `CreateController` (the _other_ issue noted in your last question). You aren't supposed to load the FXML in the constructor of the controller unless you're using `fx:root` (which you aren't and shouldn't until you understand how). You're already loading the FXML elsewhere anyway. Apply the fix there.

Comment: Hi Slaw i hope you are good, yesterday i've edit this post and you can see now that  i deleted the onMouseClicked in my login.fxml file. But the error still show

Comment: You kept the event type as `MouseEvent` but `onAction` uses `ActionEvent`. Change the parameter type. I edited my answer to your other question to clarify that.

Comment: Ok i just changed the Event type in my controller file. I'm having a new error i'm gonna make a another question.

Comment: glad you found a solution to all/most of your problems :) Just a note for future questions: don't dump a big bunch (of more or less your production code) to this site, instead strip it down to a [mcve] demonstration a single problem (for each question, these will differ). F.i. if you have a problem with a button, just show app/controller/fxml just having that single button, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Ok thanks to @Slaw he find my issue :

I was using the event type MouseEvent in my handlButtonAction function in my controller. But my button are using the function onAction which use the event : ActionEvent.

```
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        if (event.getSource() == btnClose) {
            System.exit(0);
            System.out.println("Fermeture de l'application.");
        }

        if (event.getSource() == btnConnect) {

            //login here
            if (logIn().equals("Success")) {

                // On affiche une nouvelle scene
                try {
                    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("dashboard.fxml"));
                    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
                    Stage stage = new Stage();
                    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
                    stage.setTitle("MyFit - Mon Dashboard");
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
                    stage.show();
                } catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);

                }

                //add you loading or delays - ;-)
                Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
                Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

                //stage.setMaximized(true);
                stage.close();


            }
        }
```

I've also added the good import :

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
```

Thanks for you help